# Estimation of Integral $E(x)$

Tags: integration

> How can we prove $$\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)<\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}dx<e^{-x}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\;, x>0$$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $\displaystyle f(x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}dx\;,$ Then $\displaystyle f'(x) = -\frac{e^{x}}{x}<0\;\forall x>0$

So $f(x)$ is Strictly Decreasing function.

Now How can I estimate above function, Help required, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Upper Bound Inequality**

> Note that we have the elementary inequalities
>
> $$\frac{1}{x+1}\le \log\left(1+\frac1x\right)\le \frac1x \tag 1$$

Using the left-hand side inequality in $(1)$, it is easy to see that

$$\frac{1}{x}\le \log\left(1+\frac1x\right) -\left(\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x}\right) \tag 2$$

Multiplying $(2)$ by $e^{-x}$ and integrating, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_x^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,dt& \le \int_x^\infty \left(e^{-t}\log\left(1+\frac1t\right) -e^{-t}\left(\frac{1}{t+1}-\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)\,dt\\\\
&=-\int_x^\infty \frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-t}\log\left(1+\frac1t\right)\right)\,dt\\\\
&=e^{-x}\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)
\end{align}$$

---

**Lower Bound Inequality**

> To establish the lower bound, we first show that the logarithm function satisfies the inequality
>
> $$\log\left(1+\frac2x\right)\le \frac1x+\frac1{x+2} \tag 2$$
>
> for $x>0$.

To show that $(2)$ is valid, we proceed as follows.

Define a function $f(x)$ to be

$$f(x)=\log\left(1+\frac2x\right)- \frac1x-\frac1{x+2}$$

Then, the derivative of $f(x)$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\frac{1}{x+2}-\frac1x+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{4}{x^2(x+2)^2}\\\\
&>0
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing with $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$, then $f(x)< 0$.

Now, using $(2)$, it is easy to see that

$$\frac12\left(\frac1x-\frac{1}{x+2}\right)+\frac12\log\left(1+\frac2x\right)<\frac1x \tag 3$$

Multiplying both sides of $(3)$ by $e^{-x}$ and integrating yields

$$\begin{align}
\int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,dt &> \frac12\int_x^\infty \left(e^{-t}\left(\frac1t-\frac{1}{t+2}\right)+e^{-t}\log\left(1+\frac2x\right)\right)\,dt\\\\
&=-\frac12 \int_x^\infty \frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-t}\log\left(1+\frac2t\right)\right)\,dt\\\\
&=\frac12 e^{-x}\log\left(1+\frac2x\right)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!