# Integrate from zero to infinity 1/(xe^x)

Tags: definite-integrals

I cannot solve the integral

$$\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{xe^x}.$$

I tried it by use integration by parts and gama function.

Comment: There's trouble near $0$...

Comment: The integrand function has a non-integrable singularity in a right neighbourhood of the origin, hence your integral is not converging.

Answer (score 4):

As David Mitra commented,
the integral diverges
at zero.

More precisely,
for any $c > 0$,

$\begin{array}\\
\int_{c}^{1}\frac{dx}{xe^x}
&\gt \int_{c}^{1}\frac{dx}{ex}
\qquad\text{since }e^x \le e \text{ for }0 \le x \le 1\\
&= \frac1{e}\int_{c}^{1}\frac{dx}{x}\\
&= -\frac1{e}\ln(c)\\
&= \frac1{e}\ln(\frac1{c})\\
&\to \infty
\text{ as } c \to 0\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1):

$$\Gamma(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}e^{-x}dx $$

Your integral results for $s\to 0$, which is not convergent.

Answer (score 0):

> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1797548/estimation-of-integral-ex/1797581#1797581), I showed that the function $I(x)$ as given by $I(x)=\int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,dt$ satisfies the inequalities
>
> $$\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)<\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}dx<e^{-x}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) \tag 1$$
>
> for $x>0$.

Note from the left-hand side inequality in $(1)$ that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)\right)&<\lim_{x\to 0^+}I(x)
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $\lim_{x\to 0^+}I(x)=\infty$ and the integral fails to exist as an improper integral.

Comment: I think you mean $\lim_{x \to 0}$.

Comment: @martycohen Thank you for the catch!  And actually, I meant $\lim_{x\to 0^+}$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  If the answer is not useful, I am happy to delete.  Please advise.  -Mark

Comment: Your proof is correct, but no one chose to approve it. I have had that happen, too. Perhaps they wanted a more self-contained proof. My advice is to just move on.

Comment: @martycohen Marty, thanks.  When this has happened to you, do you follow a protocol of deleting?  It seems that if the answer is not useful, then it might be considered "clutter."  -Mark

Comment: Nope. I always leave my answers and comments up, even when they are wrong. More, when someone points out an error of mine, I always thank and upvote them. I usually then correct my answer, and attribute the change to the person who pointed out the error.

Comment: I do the same when someone leaves a useful comment that either alerts an error in my solution or supplements it.  And I like to give homages to those whom I reference.  But, if my answer is not useful (no up vote) I sometimes delete or contemplate deletion.  Any way, I appreciate your reply.  You're one of the "good ones" on this site Marty!  - Mark